# How to reference Castle.DynamicProxy.IProxyTargetAccessor from Castle.Core rather than Moq?

Tags: c#, proxy, moq

I have a test which depends on both `Moq` and `Castle.Core` and trying to reference the interface `Castle.DynamicProxy.IProxyTargetAccessor`

The problem is that `Moq` embeds `Castle.Core` code within (all or part of it, not sure) and so `Castle.DynamicProxy.IProxyTargetAccessor` appears as `public` in both of these assemblies.

Now, I am creating a dynamic proxy explicitly using `Castle.Core` (cannot use the code embedded in `Moq` due to reduced visibility scope) and so the proxy implements the `Castle.Core` flavour of the interface.

Embarrassing, but I have no idea how to tell compiler to use the right interface or if it is at all possible.

**EDIT 1**

This is how the problem manifests itself in Rider:
[image]

But clicking any choice does nothing. Could be a Rider bug, because it would have to use some C# syntax to explicitly target the `Castle.Core` assembly. Not sure it exists, though.

I could rewrite the code using reflection, but I am curious if this has a compile time solution.

**EDIT 2**

Removing reference to `Castle.Core` does not work:

```
  DynamicProxyFactory.cs(20, 26): [CS0122] 'ProxyGenerator' is inaccessible due to its protection level
  DynamicProxyFactory.cs(27, 67): [CS0122] 'IInterceptor' is inaccessible due to its protection level
  DynamicProxyFactory.cs(43, 38): [CS0122] 'IInterceptor' is inaccessible due to its protection level
  DynamicProxyFactory.cs(91, 31): [CS0122] 'IInvocation' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

This is because `Moq` does not really reference `Castle.Core`. Instead, it embeds it within with the help of ilmerge, probably. But apparently it modifies the visibility scope of certain interfaces that I want to use. Hence the compilation errors when using them.

**EDIT 3**

Courtesy of Reflector:

[image]

As one can see `Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor` in the `Moq` is `internal`. While it is public in the latest version of `Castle.Core`.

Comment: Can you provide some code as an example ?

Comment: See **EDIT 1**.

Comment: To see what's happening, select the first option (from Moq.) Then select the interface and press F12 - view reference. It will show you where it's getting that interface. It's still getting it from `Castle.Core`. You could try it both ways and compare the difference. It's *probably* nothing to be concerned about because either way you're using `Castle.Core`. I'd only worry if there's some version conflict that matters.

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 2**. What am I doing wrong? And, like I said, selecting any option in Rider does nothing, which seems like a Rider bug to me.

Comment: Moq depends on Castle.Core. So when you add Moq, you'll add a reference to Castle.Core. But it's still a reference to Castle.Core. What's likely happened is that you have two references to Castle.Core: One via Moq, and another via the project you're writing tests for. If in doubt, I'd lean toward the second (not Moq) choice. That way you're referencing the same version of Castle.Core as the code you're testing. If it compiles and executes, you're good.

Comment: @ScottHannen - I respectfully disagree with your first statement. Moq does not depend on Castle.Core. It embeds it within, please see **EDIT 3**.

Comment: @mark - The [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/4.12.0) lists it as a dependency. Would it embed it if it didn't depend on it? That's not rhetorical. It sounds like there's a level of nuance to this that's beyond my knowledge.

Comment: @ScottHannen - I am using Moq 4.1. Let me upgrade and see if my woes went away,

Comment: @ScottHannen - Please, provide a formal answer. My problem was using an old version of Moq which embedded Castle.Core. The newer versions abandoned this nonsense and just reference it. I will accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @mark, I'd recommend self-answering this one. I didn't actually try anything. In order to answer it well I'd have to create a project and work through some steps. I think this is helpful because I've run into this exact conflict.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did not find how to reference a type from an assembly explicitly, but a comment by https://stackoverflow.com/users/5101046/scott-hannen helped me realize that I can upgrade `Moq` to the latest version where it no longer embeds `Castle.Core`, but references it normally.
That resolved my impediment.